# input field working fine in fiddle but not in browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a form which has three input fields.Its working fine in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/javalover_stackoverflow/4GP9c/134/) but if I run in any  browser then part of the input text field is coming out.However if i decrease the browser size then works fine.As i am using bootstrap so all the field must work same in all screen size whether its mobile or tab or computer.Please tell me how to make it function properly in all screen sizes.

**This is the screen shot showing mobile text field coming out of the div**
[image]
**This is screenshot showing proper function of text fields in small size** 
[image]

**this is code for the input fields**

```
<div class="tab-pane" id="tab2"> 
<form class="well span9" action="insertNew" method="post"> 

<table border="1" id="mytable"/>
<tr>
<th>Add</th>
<th>Username</th>
<th>EmailId</th>
<th>Mobile No</th>
</tr>
</table>

<div class="row"> 
<div class="span3"> 
<label>Name</label> 
<input type="text" id="fields" class="span4" placeholder="Your full Name" name="username" required> 

</div> 
<div class="span3"> 

<label>Email Address</label> 
<input type="email" id="fields1" class="span4" placeholder="Your email address" name="email" required> 
</div> 
<div class="span3"> 
<label>Mobile</label> 
<input type="tel" id="fields2" class="span4" placeholder="+756762462182" name="mobile" maxLength="13" required > 
</div> 
</div> 
<input type="button" id="btn1" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" value="Add">
</form> 
<div class="well span9">    <input type="button" id="btn2" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" value="Group">
</div>

</div>
```

Comment: you use span classes for input field kindly use input medium or input large or input xlarge

Comment: @SridharR thanks for the response.i did as you said.If i use input large then it works in big screen but if i decrease the browser size then input field comes out of the div.

Comment: make structure like this <div class="row-fluid"><div class="span3"></div></div>

Comment: @SridharR still the same,works in big sceen not working in small screen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try something like this,[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Qntxs/)

```
    <form class="form-horizontal">
        <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label" >Name</label>
            <div class="controls">
                <input type="text" id="fields" class="span4" placeholder="Your full Name" name="username" required />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label" >Email Address</label>
            <div class="controls">
                <input type="email" id="fields1" class="span4" placeholder="Your email address" name="email" required />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label" >Mobile</label>
            <div class="controls">
                <input type="tel" id="fields2" class="span4" placeholder="+756762462182" name="mobile" maxLength="13" required />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="control-group">
            <input type="button" id="btn1" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" value="Add">
            <input type="button" id="btn2" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" value="Group">
        </div>
    </form>
```